# How to get dropbox file name by Dropbox API in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, dropbox-api

In my app, i want to get all file name by Dropbox and download all.
My code in download

```
-(void)backupDownload{
    _tmpFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];
    [[self restClient] loadFile:@"/filename" intoPath:_tmpFilePath];

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to figure out all of the file paths/names for the files in the account so you can download them? You can use `getMetadata` or `getDelta` for that.

Comment: I'm trying to use getMetadat to get filename.  Thanks,your advice!

Comment: I- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        
        NSLog(@"Folder '%@' contains:", metadata.path);
        for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents)
        {
            [self.allFolder addObject:file.filename];
            
        }
        NSLog(@"allfoder:%@",_allFolder);
    }
  
}